# LOOKUP using 2 dataframes in Python

Tags: python, data-cleaning, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes:

df1

```
Id     CategoryId 
1       A
1       B
2       A
2       E
2       F
```

df2:

```
Id   A    B   C   D   E   F
1   
2
```

I want to do a lookup which will help me fill up the values in df2 based on the values of df1

If df1 has id = 1 and CategoryId = A then I want df2 row 1 Column A to say Y else N

Final df2 should look like:

```
 Id   A    B   C   D   E   F
 1    Y    Y   N   N   N   N
 2    Y    N   N   N   Y   Y
```

I am not sure how to do this in Python.
I would really appreciate any help on this!

Thanks

Comment: How big are your two tables? What is the result of `df1.shape` and `df2.shape`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the exact answer you provided, included entries for negative cases, you will have to create a dataframe in advance that is  all possible `Id` and `Categories` values. No pain, no gain!

Let's walk through my solution, starting with imports:

```
In [1]: from itertools import product   # will compute Id/Category possibilities

In [2]: import pandas as pd
```

Create your example dataframe

```
In [3]: df1 = df1 = pd.DataFrame(data={'Id': [1, 1, 2, 2, 2], 'CategoryId': ['A', 'B', 'A', 'E', 'F
   ...: ']})[['Id', 'CategoryId']]

In [4]: df1
Out[4]: 
   Id CategoryId
0   1          A
1   1          B
2   2          A
3   2          E
4   2          F
```

Here you must provide the possible values for the "Id" and "CategoryId" columns

```
# the ids you showed
In [5]: ids = range(1, 3)            # gives [1, 2]

# Either manually create the category values...
In [6]: cats = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']

# Or get jiggy with some Python to be more flexible:
In [7]: cats = [chr(c) for c in range(ord('A'), ord('F') + 1)]
```

Knowing the possible values for each column, we can now compute all possible combinations of those:

```
In [8]: possibilities = list(product(ids, cats))

In [9]: possibilities
Out[9]: 
[(1, 'A'),
 (1, 'B'),
 (1, 'C'),
 (1, 'D'),
 (1, 'E'),
 (1, 'F'),
 (2, 'A'),
 (2, 'B'),
 (2, 'C'),
 (2, 'D'),
 (2, 'E'),
 (2, 'F')]
```

Next we can pre-allocate a results table using the possible `Id` and `Category` values:

```
In [8]: results = pd.DataFrame(index=ids, columns=cats).fillna(0)

In [9]: results
Out[9]: 
   A  B  C  D  E  F
1  0  0  0  0  0  0
2  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

I pre-filled the dataframe with `0` values – you could use `'N'`.

Now it is a simple matter of checking to see if each possible combination appears or not and filling the coresponding cell in the `results` dataframe with your desired value (I use a `1` – you could make it `'Y'`)

```
In[10]: for i in list(df1.itertuples()):
            if (i.Id, i.CategoryId) in possibilities:
                results.loc[i.Id, i.CategoryId] = 1
```

Check the output:

```
In [11]: results
Out[11]: 
   A  B  C  D  E  F
1  1  1  0  0  0  0
2  1  0  0  0  1  1
```

[**That's a bingo!**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q5pESPQpXxE)

Comment: thank you so much! this is exactly what I was looking for. Worked perfectly

Comment: @PSnh - you're very welcome! Please consider voting up the answer or marking ione as the accepted answer!

Answer (score 2):

If you have a dataframe `df1` with two columns `Id` and `CategoryId` you can chain `get_dummies` and `groupby`, e.g.

```
>>> df2 = df1['CategoryId'].str.get_dummies().groupby(df1['Id']).max()
>>> df2
    A  B  E  F
Id
1   1  1  0  0
2   1  0  1  1
```

It's not quite the format you wanted but it avoids the lookup.

Comment: After this one can replace all `1` with `Y` and all `0` with `N` using `df.applymap`.